# How to call a function inside img src

Tags: php, wordpress

I have below code but don't want to encode the image as Base64 just link the image and get it with same function.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents(get_field('email_logo', 'option')['url'])).'" alt="The Domain" />
```

How to call the function inside img src?

Comment: You don't want to encode it but still your code says encode. Not sure I understand.

Comment: `base64_encode()` and `file_get_contents()` are not html attributes, you know. ;)

Comment: @Roko 80? Where do you see that?

Comment: @user3647971 It doesn't make sense to answer a question if you don't know what the questioner is asking. You've added an answer that _might_ be correct but it _might_ aswell be totally wrong since OP said "I don't want to encode the image as Base64"

Comment: How to call the function inside img src? I don't see many options there that he might be referring to other than the obvious

Comment: Sorry I just want the link and not encode the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only the link and it's correct as it is:

```
<img src="'.get_field('email_logo', 'option')['url'].'"/>
```

Comment: Sorry yes I just want the link and not encode the image.

Answer (score 1):

You've not shown us how this bit of code connects to the PHP around it. Assuming that there is a closed PHP block before hand, rather than this appearing in a print or heredoc...

```
?>
...
<img src="data:image/png;base64,
  <?php 
     print base64_encode(file_get_contents(
         get_field('email_logo', 'option')['url']
         ));
  ?>'" alt="The Domain" />
```